# How to include a folder in Sublime search?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Seems strange, that I can't find information on this simple topic on internet.

Let's say I want to search within specific directory for specific files. My naive approach would be:

```
Find: my_term
Where: */project_A/*, *.yml
```

While I can **exclude** some folders with `-*/project_B/*` it seems that I'm not able to **include** files.

I tried:

```
Where: */project_A/*, +*.yml 
Where: */project_A/* && *.yml
Where: */project_A/*, &*.yml
Where: */project_A/* + *.yml
```

And many more...

Answer (score 0):

From [the unofficial documentation for SublimeText](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html),

The Where field in Find in Files limits the search scope. You can define filters in several ways:

- Adding individual directories (Unix-style paths, even on Windows)
- Adding/excluding files based on wildcards
- Adding symbolic locations (, …)

Relative paths in filters are interpreted to start at the root of the active project.

To search within a specific directory and to search for specific files you can combine above listed search filters separated by commas.

```
Find: my_search_term
Where: /abs/path/to/specific/folder,specific.file
```

Comment: Separation by comma does not work, let's say I'm working within multiple projects, i.e. `base_dir/project_A`, `base_dir/project_B` and `base_dir/project_C`. Now I want to search only within yml-Files within project A. `Where: */project_A/*, *.yml` will *not* limit the search.

Comment: It is indeed answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566848/sublime-search-where-filter-expression-and-instead-of-or